# How could a class inherit from another class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass

How could a class inherit from another class? I am trying to implement it by the following example:

```
class parents(object):
      def __init__(self,dim_x, dim_y, nameprefix, sequence_number):
          if not isinstance(dim_x, (int, float, long)):
             raise TypeError("Dimension in x must be a number")
          else:
             self.sizex=str(int(dim_x))
          if not isinstance(dim_y, (int, float, long)):
             raise TypeError("Dimension in y must be a number")
          else:
             self.sizey=str(int(dim_y))
          if not isinstance(nameprefix, string_types):
              raise TypeError("The name prefix must be a string")
          else:
              self.prefix=nameprefix
          if not isinstance(sequence_number, (int, float, long)):
             raise TypeError("The sequence number must be given as a number")
          else:
             self.sqNr=str(int(sequence_number))
```

I want that the class `child` inherits the `prefix` and the `sqNr` from the `parents` class

```
class child(parents):
      def __init__(self,image_path='/vol/'):
         self.IMG_PATH=image_path
         self.ref_image=self.prefix+'_R_'+self.sqNr
         logger.debug('Reference image: %s', self.ref_image)
```

And run it with the following lines, but I get an error message:

```
>>> p=parents(300, 300, 'Test',0 )
>>> p.prefix
'Test'
>>> c=child(p)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
AttributeError: 'child' object has no attribute 'prefix'
```

I don't understand what is wrong about my implementation, any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `child` needs to take all of the arguments for the `parents`, and pass them along. You don't generally pass a superclass instance to the subclass; that's *composition*, not *inheritance*.

```
class child(parents):
    def __init__(self, dim_x, dim_y, nameprefix, 
                 sequence_number, image_path='/vol/'):
        super(child, self).__init__(dim_x, dim_y, nameprefix, 
                                    sequence_number)
        self.IMG_PATH = image_path
        ...
```

This is then called:

```
c = child(300, 300, 'Test', 0)
```

You don't need to create a `parents` instance, create the `child` directly.

*Note that, per the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the class names should really be `Parent` and `Child`.*

Comment: and what about `image_path`? If I want to change an initial value?

Comment: @Dalek same as any other default argument, pass that too: `c = child(..., 'alternative_path')`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a question: If I have a function the the `Parent` class and I want to run it in `Child` class before doing anything to use its results in the `Child` class, what should I do?

Comment: @Dalek the methods are inherited by `Child`, just use `c.method` (outside) or `self.method` (inside) as you would if they were defined directly in `Child`. If you have *also* defined `Child.method`, you will need to use `super` again to access `Parent.method`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe where do I need to use `super` again? if I want to run a method from `Parent` inside `Child` initially to use its results, do I need to use `__call__` or just run the method inside `__init__`?

Comment: @Dalek **it depends**. I can't just guess how your classes are implemented. Reread my comment carefully; you will only need `super` if `method` is implemented on both parent *and* child.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, lets say I have a method called `run(self)` in the `Parent` class and I want initially run this in `Child` because it generates bunch of files that I need to use in the methods in `Child` class and I don't want to call `parent` class separately. How should it be done?

Comment: @Dalek **is that method also implemented in the child?!** If not, just `self.run(...)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No in the `parent` class.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call superclass' `__init__` method in child class.

```
class child(parents):
    def __init__(self,image_path='/vol/'):
        super(child, self).__init__(...)  # dim_x, dim_y, nameprefix, sequence_number
        ....
```

In Python 3.x, you can use `super()` instead of `super(child, self)`.

Comment: and how could I call the second class?

Comment: @Dalek, Do you mean `child` class? In `__init__` ?

Comment: yes! should it be like :`super(child, self).__init__(self,dim_x, dim_y, nameprefix, sequence_number)`?

Comment: Is this standard? As in do you always have to call super ASWELL as put the parent class as an argument to the class?

Comment: @Dalek, Without `self`: `super(child, self).__init__(dim_x, dim_y, nameprefix, sequence_number)`

Comment: @Totem, For old-style classes (In Python-2.x, classes that does not descendant from `object` class), you can't use `super`.

Comment: @Totem a parent class attribute shouldn't generally be an argument to the child class initialiser

Comment: I'm not sure we mean the same thing, I meant parent class as an argument in this sense: class child(parent): - not a parent classes attribute

Comment: @Totem, That is a Python syntax that represent `child` is subclass of `parent` class.

Comment: yes, I know, I was basically asking why it was necessary to use both inheritance and composition together like in the class above.. instead of just inheritance. Sorry my question was very badly phrased.